# Arrange tikzpicture horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I want to arrange three pictures drawn with `tikzpicture` horizontally.  Unfortunately I can't make it work using any of the threads on a similar topic.

Thank you a lot for your help,
best regards

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}

    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot[domain=-1.3:1.3]  ({\x,{(\x)^(2)+0.1*(\x)^(4)}});

    % Optional: Add axes
    \draw[-stealth] (-1.7,0) -- (1.7,0) node[right] {$M$};
    \draw[-stealth] (0,-1.7) -- (0,1.7) node[above] {${\cal L}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{$T>T_c$}  
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}

    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot[domain=-1.4:1.4]  ({\x,{0.5*(\x)^(4)}});

    %Optional: Add axes
    \draw[-stealth] (-1.7,0) -- (1.7,0) node[right] {$M$};
    \draw[-stealth] (0,-1.7) -- (0,1.7) node[above] {${\cal L}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{$T=T_c$}  
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}

    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot[domain=-1.6:1.6]  ({\x,{-2*(\x)^(2)+(\x)^(4)}});

    % Optional: Add axes
    \draw[-stealth] (-1.7,0) -- (1.7,0) node[right] {$M$};
    \draw[-stealth] (0,-1.7) -- (0,1.7) node[above] {${\cal L}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{$T<T_c$}  
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Plot of the Landau free energy for different values $M$ and $t=\frac{T-T_c}{T_c}$ around criticality.\label{fig:phasetrans}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You have blank lines between the subfigures, which puts them into different paragraphs.

Comment: also (but unrelated tto the question) you want `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%` and `\end{tikzpicture}%` with `%`

Comment: @PascExchange If this solved your question, I suggest you to invite John Kormylo to repeat his comment as an answer, so you can accept it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Your comment solved my problem. Thank you very much. May I ask you to repost your comment as an answer?

Comment: No need (duplicate).  I was just too lazy to look one up.